# Visual Studio 2013 Displaying Output

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm new to VS. I came from Eclipse. Could anyone let me know how I can  display the outputs as they were in Eclipse?

Anytime I "Run" (Build&Run) the code, the command line show up about a second and close up.
As I don't want to add any code like cin >> xxx to keep the command line window from closing, could anyone let me know how I can get the output within the Development window? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option in Visual Studio that says 'Build and Run', its either from 'Build' or 'Run' category. You build, and then run. When you run, it *may* build the solution, if necessary.

You can run solution either **with deubugging (F5)** or **without debugging (Ctrl+F5)**. When you run **with** debugging, you may not see output. Run without debugging <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>, and output window will wait for user input.

You may use (for testing purposes), `getch`, `getchar` or other function.